# « Whatever happens » en français

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, subjonctif

> *Whatever happens*, remain calm.

Combien de façons différentes y a-t-il pour rendre en français *whatever happens* ?

Je pense à :

> N'importe ce qui se passe, restez calme.

Google Translate donne :

> Quoi qu'il arrive, restez calme.

Dans un livre de grammaire (un peu vieux quand même) j'ai aussi vu :

> Quoi qui survienne, restez calme.

Pourquoi dit-on *il arrive* et *survienne (c-à-d sans il)* ?

Comment: Seule la traduction google est correcte.

Comment: Celle que j'ai vue dans le live (quoi qui survienne, reste calme) pourquoi n'est-elle pas correcte ? En fait, c'est un livre de grammaire.

Comment: Tu te poses la bonne question, il faut dire « Quoi qu'**il** survienne. » Il faut un sujet au verbe. Quant à la première phrase on pourrait éventuellement dire : « Qu'importe ce qui se passe ... » ou bien « Peu importe ce qui se passe ... »

Comment: No, « quoi qui survienne » is fine. It's literary/vieilli but grammatical. [Example](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UVd0E-pyQn4C&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%22quoi+qui+vienne%22&source=bl&ots=VhuI5xWJ32&sig=EvGeMZ3FTN7yaW1pod68rNCXrRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijjMnd6ezbAhXm6IMKHWLGBlEQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22quoi%20qui%20vienne%22&f=false)

Comment: @Toto In support of your claim: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quoi+qui+survienne%2Cquoi+qu%27il+survienne&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquoi%20qu%27il%20survienne%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je propose que littéralement, ou de manière soutenue, `to happen` soit traduit par `advenir`.

Selon la lexicographie du TLFI, [advenir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/advenir) (paragraphe B) se définit par:

> Se produire, comme une chose possible, mais de manière non absolument prévisible, quoique attendue.

Autrement, les expressions suivantes en saisissent aussi le sens:

- Peu importe/N'importe ce qui ce passe...
- Quoi qu'il arrive/survienne...

ainsi que leurs agencements possibles

Comment: `quoi qu'il arrive` reste quand même la forme la plus utilisée à mon sens

Comment: Je ne crois jamais avoir vu ou entendu "N'importe ce qu'il" au lieu de "Peu importe ce qu'il" ou de "Quoi qu'il"

Answer (score 2):

I never encountered your first proposition. We usually say:

- `Quoiqu'il arrive, <...>`
- `Peu importe ce qui se passe, <...>` (less formal)
- `Quoiqu'il advienne/survienne, <...>`